# How can I create a simple private pool for tracking hashes for me and my friends trying to mine a block by ourselves?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, mining-pools, full-node, mining-pool-setup, random-x

For context, me and my friends have assembled a little mining group for fun and we currently mine whatever is most profitable on cpu and gpu to the same address on the same pools. I programmed a little discord bot that runs on my home server to use the pools apis to track mining hours, profitability, and our total funds which creates a little competition between us for who can gain the most hours among other things. I've been really interested in monero recently and thought it would be a fun idea to try and mine a block ourselves which could be done in a few months and support decentralization, and I want a way to have a simple leaderboard of how many hashes everyone has committed so I thought I could try to make a simple pool to do that for me. So I then started to research how this could be accomplished. this is where the problem lies. I've found almost no documentation on this subject, and that combined with my poor knowledge of the code side of monero, mining, and pools in general has left me with almost no leads, so that is what I'm looking for today. From my understanding I will need a node which I should run with the daemon from the cli wallet but could possibly be handled by pool software? but then where do I get started with making a pool/editing existing software? or is it the likely scenario of being too complicated for me. I apologize for the open ended questions but I'm kind of short on options, any support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you already check whether you could set this up properly? https://github.com/jtgrassie/monero-pool

Comment: Yep, that's my first stop, I shouldn't have problems considering the step-by-step tutorial.